# Upload photos to Facebook Album from an app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've used

```
'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,status_update'
```

The error I'm getting is

> Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data thrown in facebook.php on line 589

My upload code:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'My Friend\'s');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath('http://mysite/img/img.jpg');
$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
```

I just want to upload the photo to an existing album or already created album. What would working code be?

Another code

```
$photo_details = array('message'=>$_REQUEST['arttitle'],'source'=> '@' . realpath( $_FILES[file]tmp_name]));
$facebook->api('/me/photos','POST',$photo_details);
```

results in

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#324) Requires upload file thrown in facebook.php on line 522

I tried other answers from Stack Overflow, but none of them worked in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the code below, and it worked perfectly.

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$album_details = array(
    'message'=> 'album description goes here',
    'name'=> 'album name goes here'
);
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

// Upload a picture
$photo_details = array(
    'message'=> 'photo description'
);
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath('/the/path/to/your/image.jpg');
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$create_album['id'].'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);

echo $upload_photo['id']; // The id of your newly uploaded pic.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `realpath()` with URLs. If the image is located on the same server, try to provide that path instead. Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509326/upload-images-to-a-specific-facebook-album/4541400#4541400) for more info.

Comment: do i need to use 'image' => '@'or just the path without @

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(  
    'message' => 'My Friend\'s',  
    "access_token" => "urtoken",  
    "image" => '@' . realpath('http://mysite/img/img.jpg'); 
);  


$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

try this code

Comment: can you tell me how to get the access token ? Recently i read at FB that to publish status app must have a valid access token, but i can still post status with out using the access token !

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#324) Requires upload file thrown in facebook.php on line 522

Comment: read this tutorial regrading access token http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/