# How to upload photo to a existing album created by application?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload image to an album if exist else create new album - Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260489/upload-image-to-an-album-if-exist-else-create-new-album-facebook)

I am using this code to create a album and upload a photo to a user's profile

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
//Create an album
$album_details = array(
        'message'=> 'my album name',
        'name'=> 'my album name'
);
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

//Get album ID of the album you've just created
$album_uid = $create_album['id'];
$args = array('message' => '');
                copy($image, 'tmp/file.jpeg');
                $args['image'] = '@' . realpath('tmp/file.jpeg');
                $data = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $args);
                unlink('tmp/file.jpeg');
```

This code works fine but I have one problem, every time a user uploads a photo it creates a new album each time.  What i want to do is create an album the first time only and if user uploads a photo a 2nd time it should get uploaded to the album created first time.
How i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same album id as you did the first time you uploaded.

Comment: how i will get the album id in 2nd time created at the first time

Comment: You can save it to a database, for example.