# How to check if Facebook album already exists without FQL

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Now that FQL has been deprecated, is there an efficient way to verify if an album already exists (by name since I don't have the album ID available)?  I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260489/upload-image-to-an-album-if-exist-else-create-new-album-facebook) post, but the top-rated answer relies on FQL.  I'm hoping I don't have to retrieve all albums and compare each resulting album name against the name in question.

If I do have to retrieve all albums and compare the results, does anyone have a handy Javascript snippet they can share?

Comment: P.S.  I've tried various ways of forming the FB graph URL to search by name, but no luck.  For example: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me/albums?name="MyAlbum"&access_token=<token>

Comment: The API will not let you search by the album name because that field is not indexed.

Comment: So the service response is in JSON format so I'm guessing that I need to be more precise about how I declare the variable and handle the result.  Or it could be that the service call is asynchronous and I'm trying to parse the results before completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query albums by name, you'll have to just request the entire list and "manually" search for the desired album in the results.

You can use this endpoint to fetch all of the albums for the current user:

```
me/albums?fields=name
```

This will return results in the following format:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Profile Pictures", 
      "id": "XXXX", 
      "created_time": "2010-08-24T07:44:36+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Cover Photos", 
      "id": "YYYY", 
      "created_time": "2011-09-22T22:58:07+0000"
    }, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

Then to locate the desired album (`my_album`), you would use some code similar to this:

```
results = get_albums(); // making the actual API call
found_album = false;
for ( var i = 0; i < results.data.length; i++ ){
  if ( results.data[ i ][ "name" ] == "my_album" ){
    found_album = true;
    break; // no need to continue searching
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx Lix!  My code is failing at the point where it tries to store the results.  I'm sure I'm being dumb, but this line is failing:

var results = servicename.execute();

Comment: Thanks a million. I wanted to php code and this is working  with php code.
$album = $facebook->api('/ALBUM_ID/photos');
This is working correctly when album has 2 photos.  is have 2 photos then not returned. Thanks again. VOTED !!!

Answer (score 0):

Phew!

This is what I came up with after playing with Lix's snippet a bit.  I'd love to know if there is a more efficient way to do this than using models and local variables to handle the service response.

Appery.io Model:

```
fbAlbumList [Array]
    fbAlbumList[i] [Object]
            name [String]
            id [String]
```

Appery.io Local Variable

```
fbAlbums - Local Storage - Type fbAlbumList
```

JS

```
var found_album = false;
var results = [];

results = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fbAlbums'));  // fbAlbums is a model/local variable
for (var i = 0; i < results.length-1; i++) {
    if (results[i].name == <comparison name>) {
        found_album = true;
        break; // no need to continue searching
    }
}
```