# photo not upload to facebook album using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Photo not uploaded in facebook album after giving enough file upload permission.... i have also refered related question for graph api still there is no success...

```
 $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,photo_upload,can_upload'));

                        $album_details = array(
                                'message'=> 'Testing Description For Pic',
                                'name'=> 'Testing Pic Album'
                        );

                        $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);






                        $args = array(
                                'message' => 'Photo from application',
                                'image' => '@'.$imgURL
                        );



                        $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$create_album['id'].'/photos?access_token='.$aut_key;
                        $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
                        $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced the same problem,

Please try to make sure that $imgURL is the relative image location on your server and not a generic web url of the image.

Also, try to crosscheck here http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509326/upload-images-to-a-specific-facebook-album also checked this article

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code it works for me

```
<?php
    $img = 'image.jpg';
    $args = array(
       'message' => 'Photo from application',
        'access_token'=>urlencode('Your Access token'),
    );
    $args[basename($img)] = '@'.realpath($img);

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($data,true);

    if($response[id]>0){
    // yes
    }

    print_r(json_decode($data,true));

    print_r(curl_error($ch));
?>
```

May be it helps you.

Comment: Simple use curl, no need to use graph api.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
 'image' => '@'.$imgURL
```

to

```
 'source' => '@'.$imgURL
```

The Facebook API specifes that "source" should contain the image information. There is no mention in the image API of a "image" field when uploading images.

[Facebook Photo API DOC](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

Comment: Please consider adding some commentary explaining *why* this is an answer.

Comment: Can you echo $imgURL and post what it echos?

Comment: $imgURL echos image url path                                         e.g http://ds9.ssl.berkeley.edu/imageviewer/images/images2/latest_eit_284_full.jpg

Comment: no error messege occured....it create new album in facebook using graph api but inside the album no image uploaded that r we giving into the $imgURL......